# What could be causing an error while starting the Hybris Server with code in spring.xml?

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, sap-commerce-cloud, hybris-data-hub

Error creating Spring application context. Shutting down hybris platform since the system cannot be used without working Spring context...

```
INFO  [localhost-startStop-1] [HybrisContextFactory] Initializing <<global>> Spring ApplicationContext took: (107.4 Î¼s)
de.hybris.platform.core.UninstantiableCoreApplicationContextException: Error creating Spring application context.
        at de.hybris.platform.core.AbstractTenant.doStartupSafe(AbstractTenant.java:796)
        at de.hybris.platform.core.AbstractTenant.doStartUp(AbstractTenant.java:725)
        at de.hybris.platform.core.Registry.assureTenantStarted(Registry.java:650)
        at de.hybris.platform.core.Registry.activateTenant(Registry.java:711)
        at de.hybris.platform.core.Registry.setCurrentTenant(Registry.java:560)
        at de.hybris.platform.core.Registry.activateMasterTenant(Registry.java:619)
        at de.hybris.platform.core.Registry.startup(Registry.java:438)
        at de.hybris.platform.core.ClassLoaderUtils.executeWithWebClassLoaderParentIfNeeded(ClassLoaderUtils.java:35)
        at de.hybris.platform.spring.HybrisContextLoaderListener.startRegistry(HybrisContextLoaderListener.java:319)
        at de.hybris.platform.spring.HybrisContextLoaderListener.doInitWebApplicationContext(HybrisContextLoaderListener.java:205)
        at de.hybris.platform.spring.HybrisContextLoaderListener.initWebApplicationContext(HybrisContextLoaderListener.java:192)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:103)
        at de.hybris.platform.spring.HybrisContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(HybrisContextLoaderListener.java:88)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4689)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5155)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1412)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1402)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.FatalBeanException: Context hybris Global Context Factory  couldn't  be created correctly due to,


 Error creating bean with name 'fetchDataService' defined in class path resource [trainingcore-spring.xml]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 2; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCurrentlyInCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'fetchDataService': Requested bean is currently in creation: Is there an unresolvable circular reference?
        at de.hybris.platform.core.HybrisContextFactory.build(HybrisContextFactory.java:307)
        at de.hybris.platform.core.HybrisContextFactory$GlobalContextFactory.buildSelf(HybrisContextFactory.java:179)
        at de.hybris.platform.core.HybrisContextFactory$GlobalContextFactory.build(HybrisContextFactory.java:165)
        at de.hybris.platform.core.HybrisContextHolder.getGlobalInstanceCached(HybrisContextHolder.java:122)
        at de.hybris.platform.core.HybrisContextHolder.getGlobalInstance(HybrisContextHolder.java:101)
        at de.hybris.platform.core.HybrisContextHolder.getAppCtxFactory(HybrisContextHolder.java:152)
        at de.hybris.platform.core.HybrisContextHolder.getApplicationInstance(HybrisContextHolder.java:78)
        at de.hybris.platform.core.AbstractTenant.createCoreApplicationContext(AbstractTenant.java:753)
        at de.hybris.platform.core.AbstractTenant.doStartupSafe(AbstractTenant.java:792)
        ... 21 more


Error creating Spring application context. Shutting down hybris platform since the system cannot be used without working Spring context...
INFO  [localhost-startStop-7] [HybrisContextFactory] Initializing <<global>> Spring ApplicationContext took: (23.50 Î¼s)
de.hybris.platform.core.UninstantiableCoreApplicationContextException: Error creating Spring application context.
        at de.hybris.platform.core.AbstractTenant.doStartupSafe(AbstractTenant.java:796)
        at de.hybris.platform.core.AbstractTenant.doStartUp(AbstractTenant.java:725)
        at de.hybris.platform.core.Registry.assureTenantStarted(Registry.java:650)
        at de.hybris.platform.core.Registry.activateTenant(Registry.java:711)
        at de.hybris.platform.core.Registry.setCurrentTenant(Registry.java:560)
        at de.hybris.platform.core.Registry.activateMasterTenant(Registry.java:619)
        at de.hybris.platform.core.Registry.startup(Registry.java:438)
        at de.hybris.platform.core.ClassLoaderUtils.executeWithWebClassLoaderParentIfNeeded(ClassLoaderUtils.java:35)
        at de.hybris.platform.spring.HybrisContextLoaderListener.startRegistry(HybrisContextLoaderListener.java:319)
        at de.hybris.platform.spring.HybrisContextLoaderListener.doInitWebApplicationContext(HybrisContextLoaderListener.java:205)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:103)
        at de.hybris.platform.spring.HybrisContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(HybrisContextLoaderListener.java:88)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4689)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5155)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1412)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1402)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.FatalBeanException: Context hybris Global Context Factory  couldn't  be created correctly due to,

 Error creating bean with name 'fetchDataService' defined in class path resource [trainingcore-spring.xml]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 2; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCurrentlyInCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'fetchDataService': Requested bean is currently in creation: Is there an unresolvable circular reference?
        at de.hybris.platform.core.HybrisContextFactory.build(HybrisContextFactory.java:307)
        at de.hybris.platform.core.HybrisContextFactory$GlobalContextFactory.buildSelf(HybrisContextFactory.java:179)
        at de.hybris.platform.core.HybrisContextFactory$GlobalContextFactory.build(HybrisContextFactory.java:165)
        at de.hybris.platform.core.HybrisContextHolder.getGlobalInstanceCached(HybrisContextHolder.java:122)
        at de.hybris.platform.core.HybrisContextHolder.getGlobalInstance(HybrisContextHolder.java:101)
        at de.hybris.platform.core.HybrisContextHolder.getAppCtxFactory(HybrisContextHolder.java:152)
        at de.hybris.platform.core.HybrisContextHolder.getApplicationInstance(HybrisContextHolder.java:78)
        at de.hybris.platform.core.AbstractTenant.createCoreApplicationContext(AbstractTenant.java:753)
        at de.hybris.platform.core.AbstractTenant.doStartupSafe(AbstractTenant.java:792)
        ... 21 more
Error creating Spring application context. Shutting down hybris platform since the system cannot be used without working Spring context...
INFO  [Thread-3] [HybrisContextFactory] Initializing <<global>> Spring ApplicationContext took: (21.60 Î¼s)

ERROR [Thread-3] [JMXBeanLoader] Can't unregister jmxbeans on shutdown of the tenant <<master>>
org.springframework.beans.FatalBeanException: Context hybris Global Context Factory  couldn't  be created correctly due to, Error creating bean with name 'fetchDataService' defined in class path resource [trainingcore-spring.xml]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 2; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCurrentlyInCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'fetchDataService': Requested bean is currently in creation: Is there an unresolvable circular reference?
        at de.hybris.platform.core.HybrisContextFactory.build(HybrisContextFactory.java:307) ~[coreserver.jar:?]
        at de.hybris.platform.core.HybrisContextFactory$GlobalContextFactory.buildSelf(HybrisContextFactory.java:179) ~[coreserver.jar:?]
        at de.hybris.platform.core.HybrisContextFactory$GlobalContextFactory.build(HybrisContextFactory.java:165) ~[coreserver.jar:?]
        at de.hybris.platform.core.HybrisContextHolder.getGlobalInstanceCached(HybrisContextHolder.java:122) ~[coreserver.jar:?]
        at de.hybris.platform.core.HybrisContextHolder.getGlobalInstance(HybrisContextHolder.java:101) ~[coreserver.jar:?]
        at de.hybris.platform.core.Registry.getSingletonGlobalApplicationContext(Registry.java:1116) ~[coreserver.jar:?]
        at de.hybris.platform.core.JMXBeanLoader.getMBeanRegistry(JMXBeanLoader.java:141) ~[coreserver.jar:?]
        at de.hybris.platform.core.JMXBeanLoader.beforeTenantShutDown(JMXBeanLoader.java:104) [coreserver.jar:?]
        at de.hybris.platform.core.AbstractTenant.notifyTenantListenersBeforeShutdown(AbstractTenant.java:1315) [coreserver.jar:?]
        at de.hybris.platform.core.AbstractTenant.doShutdown(AbstractTenant.java:996) [coreserver.jar:?]
ERROR [Thread-3] [RegionCacheAdapter] Unable to clear cache. Failed on region entityCacheRegion. Last key null null
java.lang.IllegalStateException: The entityCacheRegion Cache is not alive (STATUS_SHUTDOWN)
        at net.sf.ehcache.Cache$CacheStatus.checkAlive(Cache.java:4075) ~[ehcache-2.9.0.jar:2.9.0]
        at net.sf.ehcache.Cache.checkStatus(Cache.java:2766) ~[ehcache-2.9.0.jar:2.9.0]
        at net.sf.ehcache.Cache.getKeys(Cache.java:2066) ~[ehcache-2.9.0.jar:2.9.0]
        at de.hybris.platform.regioncache.region.impl.EHCacheRegion.getAllKeys(EHCacheRegion.java:423) ~[coreserver.jar:?]
        at de.hybris.platform.cache.impl.RegionCacheAdapter.clear(RegionCacheAdapter.java:283) [coreserver.jar:?]
        at de.hybris.platform.core.AbstractTenant.shutdownCache(AbstractTenant.java:1140) [coreserver.jar:?]
        at de.hybris.platform.core.AbstractTenant.doShutdown(AbstractTenant.java:1014) [coreserver.jar:?]
        at de.hybris.platform.core.AbstractTenant.doShutDown(AbstractTenant.java:957) [coreserver.jar:?]
        at de.hybris.platform.core.Registry.destroy(Registry.java:325) [coreserver.jar:?]
        at de.hybris.platform.util.RedeployUtilities.shutdown(RedeployUtilities.java:67) [coreserver.jar:?]
        at de.hybris.platform.util.RedeployUtilities$1.internalRun(RedeployUtilities.java:32) [coreserver.jar:?]
        at de.hybris.platform.core.threadregistry.RegistrableThread.run(RegistrableThread.java:124) [coreserver.jar:?]
WARN  [Thread-3] [AbstractTenant] The entityCacheRegion Cache is not alive (STATUS_SHUTDOWN)
java.lang.IllegalStateException: The entityCacheRegion Cache is not alive (STATUS_SHUTDOWN)
        at net.sf.ehcache.Cache$CacheStatus.checkAlive(Cache.java:4075) ~[ehcache-2.9.0.jar:2.9.0]
        at net.sf.ehcache.Cache.checkStatus(Cache.java:2766) ~[ehcache-2.9.0.jar:2.9.0]
        at net.sf.ehcache.Cache.getKeys(Cache.java:2066) ~[ehcache-2.9.0.jar:2.9.0]
        at de.hybris.platform.regioncache.region.impl.EHCacheRegion.getAllKeys(EHCacheRegion.java:423) ~[coreserver.jar:?]
        at de.hybris.platform.cache.impl.RegionCacheAdapter.clear(RegionCacheAdapter.java:283) ~[coreserver.jar:?]
        at de.hybris.platform.core.AbstractTenant.shutdownCache(AbstractTenant.java:1140) [coreserver.jar:?]
        at de.hybris.platform.core.AbstractTenant.doShutdown(AbstractTenant.java:1014) [coreserver.jar:?]
        at de.hybris.platform.core.AbstractTenant.doShutDown(AbstractTenant.java:957) [coreserver.jar:?]
        at de.hybris.platform.core.Registry.destroy(Registry.java:325) [coreserver.jar:?]
        at de.hybris.platform.util.RedeployUtilities.shutdown(RedeployUtilities.java:67) [coreserver.jar:?]
        at de.hybris.platform.util.RedeployUtilities$1.internalRun(RedeployUtilities.java:32) [coreserver.jar:?]
        at de.hybris.platform.core.threadregistry.RegistrableThread.run(RegistrableThread.java:124) [coreserver.jar:?]


ERROR [Thread-3] [RegionCacheAdapter] Unable to clear cache. Failed on region entityCacheRegion. Last key null null
java.lang.IllegalStateException: The entityCacheRegion Cache is not alive (STATUS_SHUTDOWN)
        at net.sf.ehcache.Cache$CacheStatus.checkAlive(Cache.java:4075) ~[ehcache-2.9.0.jar:2.9.0]
        at net.sf.ehcache.Cache.checkStatus(Cache.java:2766) ~[ehcache-2.9.0.jar:2.9.0]
        at net.sf.ehcache.Cache.getKeys(Cache.java:2066) ~[ehcache-2.9.0.jar:2.9.0]
        at de.hybris.platform.regioncache.region.impl.EHCacheRegion.getAllKeys(EHCacheRegion.java:423) ~[coreserver.jar:?]
        at de.hybris.platform.cache.impl.RegionCacheAdapter.clear(RegionCacheAdapter.java:283) [coreserver.jar:?]
        at de.hybris.platform.cache.impl.RegionCacheAdapter.destroy(RegionCacheAdapter.java:512) [coreserver.jar:?]
        at de.hybris.platform.core.AbstractTenant.shutdownCache(AbstractTenant.java:1150) [coreserver.jar:?]
        at de.hybris.platform.core.AbstractTenant.doShutdown(AbstractTenant.java:1014) [coreserver.jar:?]
        at de.hybris.platform.core.AbstractTenant.doShutDown(AbstractTenant.java:957) [coreserver.jar:?]
        at de.hybris.platform.core.Registry.destroy(Registry.java:325) [coreserver.jar:?]
        at 
de.hybris.platform.core.threadregistry.RegistrableThread.run(RegistrableThread.java:124) [coreserver.jar:?]
WARN  [Thread-3] [AbstractTenant] The entityCacheRegion Cache is not alive (STATUS_SHUTDOWN)
java.lang.IllegalStateException: The entityCacheRegion Cache is not alive (STATUS_SHUTDOWN)
        at net.sf.ehcache.Cache$CacheStatus.checkAlive(Cache.java:4075) ~[ehcache-2.9.0.jar:2.9.0]
        at net.sf.ehcache.Cache.checkStatus(Cache.java:2766) ~[ehcache-2.9.0.jar:2.9.0]
        at net.sf.ehcache.Cache.getKeys(Cache.java:2066) ~[ehcache-2.9.0.jar:2.9.0]
        at de.hybris.platform.regioncache.region.impl.EHCacheRegion.getAllKeys(EHCacheRegion.java:423) ~[coreserver.jar:?]
        at de.hybris.platform.cache.impl.RegionCacheAdapter.clear(RegionCacheAdapter.java:283) ~[coreserver.jar:?]
        at de.hybris.platform.cache.impl.RegionCacheAdapter.destroy(RegionCacheAdapter.java:512) ~[coreserver.jar:?]
        at jar:?]
        at de.hybris.platform.core.AbstractTenant.doShutDown(AbstractTenant.java:957) [coreserver.jar:?]
        at de.hybris.platform.core.Registry.destroy(Registry.java:325) [coreserver.jar:?]
        at de.hybris.platform.util.RedeployUtilities.shutdown(RedeployUtilities.java:67) [coreserver.jar:?]
        at de.hybris.platform.util.RedeployUtilities$1.internalRun(RedeployUtilities.java:32) [coreserver.jar:?]
        at de.hybris.platform.core.threadregistry.RegistrableThread.run(RegistrableThread.java:124) [coreserver.jar:?]
INFO  [Thread-3] [DefaultClusterNodeManagementService] Unregistering assigned cluster node id 0...
INFO  [AfterSaveEventPublisher-master] [DefaultAfterSaveListenerRegistry] AfterSaveEventPublisher-master has been interrupted/terminated but without InterruptedException - stopping now.
Exception in thread "AfterSaveEventPublisher-master" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can not activate tenant <<master>> since it has no application context created
        at de.hybris.platform.core.Registry.assureTenantStarted(Registry.java:674)
        at de.hybris.platform.core.Registry.activateTenant(Registry.java:711)
        at de.hybris.platform.core.Registry.setCurrentTenant(Registry.java:560)
        at de.hybris.platform.tx.DefaultAfterSaveListenerRegistry$AfterSaveEventPublisherThread.internalRun(DefaultAfterSaveListenerRegistry.java:242)
        at de.hybris.platform.core.threadregistry.RegistrableThread.run(RegistrableThread.java:124)
<-- Wrapper Stopped
C:\dcxtraining2005\hybris\bin\platform>m
'm' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

``    This is bean registration in spring.xml

```
  <bean id ="fetchDataService" class ="com.training.core.service.impl.DefaultErpFetchDataService">
  <constructor-arg name="restTemplate" ref="erpRestTemplate"/>
  </bean> ``
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: You seem to have a circular reference problem (bean A is dependent on Bean B and Bean B is dependent on Bean A). Check `fetchDataService` bean